# How to retrieve the original data from nls model in R?

Tags: r, nls

non-linear least square (`nls()` function in core R) generates a list object with a bunch of useful info inside, is there also the original data that were the input of the model? I suspect yes, as functions as `predict()` or `fitted()` are actually defined on this object and generate predictions in ranges of the original fitted data. So, how can one access this data through the model object?

Imagine this setting

```
# generating some data
generated_data <- hist(rnorm(1000, 50, 10))
data <- data.frame(x = generated_data$mids, y = generated_data$counts) 

# a dummy model
my_model <- nls(y ~ N * dnorm(x, m, s), data=data, start=c(m=55, s=12, N=sum(data$y)) )
```

How can I access `x` and `y` values by the `my_model` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data indeed is there but it's a bit buried within the environment of the model that is also saved within the object, I figured it out looking at [the source code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/nls.R). You can access the input values of through `getEnv()` function which is available through the `m` object and that is part of the list returned by `nls`.

So on the dummy example:

```
# generating some data
generated_data <- hist(rnorm(1000, 50, 10))
data <- data.frame(x = generated_data$mids, y = generated_data$counts) 

# a dummy model
my_model <- nls(y ~ N * dnorm(x, m, s), data=data, start=c(m=55, s=12, N=sum(data$y)) ) 

original_x_values <- my_model$m$getEnv()$x
original_y_values <- my_model$m$getEnv()$y
```

Comment: I think this should be marked as the correct answer. Understanding how modeling results are stored is at least as important as "just getting the answer".

Answer (score 3):

Broom has nice features for dealing with many models. You can use `broom::augment()` with added benefits :)

If you don't want to use broom, then Kamil's answer works.

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
my_model %>% augment()
```

```
# A tibble: 13 × 4
      x     y .fitted  .resid
  <dbl> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1  22.5     6    4.27   1.73 
2  27.5    18   15.1    2.88 
3  32.5    45   41.6    3.36 
4  37.5    94   89.1    4.87 
5  42.5   137  148.   -11.3  
6  47.5   191  192.    -0.740
# … with 7 more rows
```

Comment: also `nlme::getData()`

Comment: excellent! Reminds me to take a look at this package - it's been a while.